# Is the built-in Python module sqlite3 using the global computer's sqlite3 shared library, or is it statically linked?

Tags: python, linux, sqlite, static-linking, dynamic-linking

On a Linux Ubuntu (with Python 3.5, but it's similar on more recent versions), here is how the built-in module `sqlite3` is called:

```
import sqlite3 
==> sqlite3/__init__.py:    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import * 
==> sqlite3/dbapi2.py:      from _sqlite3 import * 
==> /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

How to reliably know if:

- `_sqlite3.**.so` has the Sqlite library statically linked in it?
- or if `_sqlite3.**.so` is calling a computer global shared library such as `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so`?

Comment: Example `$ ldd /usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` → libsqlite3.so.0, {libicu* x3 different},  libpython3.6m.so.1.0, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `_sqlite3.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` *is* using a number of shared libraries.

Example

```
 $ ldd /usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
        .
        libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007f0701a4c000)
        libpython3.6m.so.1.0 => /usr/lib64/libpython3.6m.so.1.0 (0x00007f0701577000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f0701557000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f070139a000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f0701395000)
        libicui18n.so.65 => /usr/lib64/libicui18n.so.65 (0x00007f070109c000)
        libicuuc.so.65 => /usr/lib64/libicuuc.so.65 (0x00007f0700eb4000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f0700d72000)
        libintl.so.8 => /lib64/libintl.so.8 (0x00007f0700d65000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f0700d60000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0701dd3000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f0700b90000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f0700b74000)
        libicudata.so.65 => /usr/lib64/libicudata.so.65 (0x00007f0700b71000)
```

Comment: Thanks! Conclusion: it uses the shared library `/usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0`, so it's not statically linked.